# Removing Duplicate Nodes from Xml using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml like

```
<xml>
 <Test>
  <TestData>
   <TestData>
    <Name>Alex</Name>
   </TestData>
  </TestData>
 </Test>
 <Name>
 <NameData>
   <NameData>
    <Name>Chris</Name>
   </NameData>
  </NameData>
 </Name>
</xml>
```

I want to remove the duplicate nodes of TestData and NameData from the xml so that xml looks something like this

```
 <xml>
     <Test>
      <TestData>
        <Name>Alex</Name>
      </TestData>
     </Test>
     <Name>
     <NameData>
        <Name>Chris</Name>
      </NameData>
     </Name>
    </xml>
```

I have tried searching for some clue but every recommendation I come across has the node name specified. I have xmls which has large amount. Any c# class/method I can use to remove the duplicate.

Comment: So what *exactly* are the criteria? Just elements which contain a single child element, where that child element has the same name?

Comment: Also: are there any nodes where you've got *triple* nesting, e.g. `<x><x><x><y>Foo</y></x></x></x>` or is it just double?

Comment: where that child element has the same name. There is no triple nesting, it is just double. So the criteria is to remove that testdata and namedata duplicate node.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to XML makes this reasonably easy *if* some assumptions are met:

- There are no elements with "triple duplication" e.g. `<TestData><TestData><TestData>`. I'm sure it's feasible to work around that, but it's trickier.
- We don't need to worry about non-element children (e.g. where `TestData` has text content as well as the nested `TestData` element)
- We don't need to worry about attributes

In that case, it's just a matter of checking that there's exactly one child element, and that it's got the same name as the parent element... then replace it.

Here's some code to do exactly that:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var replacements = doc.Descendants()
            .Select(GetReplacementForParent)
            .Where(r => r != null)
            .ToList();
        foreach (var replacement in replacements)
        {
            replacement.Parent.ReplaceWith(replacement);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
    }

    static XElement GetReplacementForParent(XElement element)
    {
        var child = element.Elements(element.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        // TODO: Use a more efficient approach for counting children, maybe.
        // TODO: Check for non-element content? Check for attributes?
        return child != null && element.Elements().Count() == 1
            ? child : null;
    }
}
```